# How to compute gradients in tf.py_func ops?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a python program for calculating intersections between rectangles as this:

```
def clip(subjectPolygon, clipPolygon):
   def inside(p):
      return(cp2[0]-cp1[0])*(p[1]-cp1[1]) > (cp2[1]-cp1[1])*(p[0]-cp1[0])

   def computeIntersection():
      dc = [ cp1[0] - cp2[0], cp1[1] - cp2[1] ]
      dp = [ s[0] - e[0], s[1] - e[1] ]
      n1 = cp1[0] * cp2[1] - cp1[1] * cp2[0]
      n2 = s[0] * e[1] - s[1] * e[0] 
      n3 = 1.0 / (dc[0] * dp[1] - dc[1] * dp[0])
      return [(n1*dp[0] - n2*dc[0]) * n3, (n1*dp[1] - n2*dc[1]) * n3]

   outputList = subjectPolygon
   cp1 = clipPolygon[-1]

   for clipVertex in clipPolygon:
      cp2 = clipVertex
      inputList = outputList
      outputList = []
      s = inputList[-1]

      for subjectVertex in inputList:
         e = subjectVertex
         if inside(e):
            if not inside(s):
               outputList.append(computeIntersection())
            outputList.append(e)
         elif inside(s):
            outputList.append(computeIntersection())
         s = e
      cp1 = cp2
   return(outputList)

def PolygonArea(corners):
    n = len(corners) # of corners
    area = 0.0
    for i in range(n):
        j = (i + 1) % n
        area += corners[i][0] * corners[j][1]
        area -= corners[j][0] * corners[i][1]
    area = abs(area) / 2.0
    return area
```

I forward an image in the network and as an output it gives a rectangle. From this predicted rectangle and the ground truth rectangle (labeled data) I use the programs above with the help of `tf.py_func` to calculate the intersection over union. I use *IoU* to construct the loss function, then to be feed in the optimizer. But, by doing this I get the error:

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph
>   for ops that do not support gradients, between variables ...

and it gives a list of all my variables.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve the problem; maybe by writing the functions in TF or making the `tf.py_func` to compute gradients?

If it's of interest, this is the [file](https://github.com/tnikolla/grasp-detection/blob/master/grasp_det.py) and then navigate the repository.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define gradient for py_func yourself, see [this](https://gist.github.com/kingspp/3ec7d9958c13b94310c1a365759aa3f4) for an example